# jpegData() from UIImageView is nil

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-storage, kingfisher

I'm trying to extract the image data from a `UIImageView` so I can upload it to Firebase Storage. However, `iv.image?.jpegData()` is returning nil. I'm using the standard [Kingfisher library](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher#kingfisher-101) method to add the image from the URL to the `UIImageView`.

Here's my code:

```
    let url = URL(string: "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1229497999392477186/BMXkjVEJ_400x400.jpg")
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.kf.setImage(with: url)
    if let png = iv.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: .leastNormalMagnitude){
        filePath.putData(png, metadata: nil){ metadata, error in
            print("metadata: \(metadata) |error: \(error)") // doesn't print
        }
    }
```

Any idea why `iv.image?.jpegData()` is nil? I've also tried `iv.image?.pngData()` and that is also nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setImage` doesn't change the `image` property automatically. It has to potentially download the image from the Internet, which takes time.

Luckily, you can know when the download is completed by adding a `completionHandler`:

```
iv.kf.setImage(with: url, completionHandler: { result in
    guard case .success(let imageResource) = result else { 
        // an error has occurred!
        return 
    }
    if let png = imageResource.image.jpegData(compressionQuality: .leastNormalMagnitude){
        filePath.putData(png, metadata: nil){ metadata, error in
            print("metadata: \(metadata) |error: \(error)") // doesn't print
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

As

```
iv.kf.setImage(with: url)
```

is asynchronous `iv.image?.jpegData()/iv.image?.pngData()` will be nil until the image is loaded from the server

Comment: Additional note: There should be a version of that method with a closure which will be called on completion (once the image is downloaded).

Comment: @Larme yes i think it's what the op needs

Answer (score 1):

As @Sh_Khan has explained you need to wait for the `async` call to finish. Here's is the fix:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1229497999392477186/BMXkjVEJ_400x400.jpg")
let iv = UIImageView()
iv.kf.setImage(with: url) { _ in
    if let png = iv.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: .leastNormalMagnitude){
        filePath.putData(png, metadata: nil){ metadata, error in
            print("metadata: \(metadata) |error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```